# "Zum einen, weil" korrekt interpungieren

Tags: punctuation

Wieder einmal schlug heute meine Interpunktionsschwäche zu, als ich folgenden Satz interpungieren musste:

> Den unansehnlichen Yang Chengfang (阳成方) ehelicht sie zum einen, weil sie keine Jungfrau ist, zum anderen, um Mitglied einer Arbeiterfamilie zu werden.

Ist nun dieser Satz richtig interpungiert? Ich habe das Internet nach Beispielen durchsucht und folgende gefunden, die sich auf den ersten Blick zu widersprechen scheinen:

> Lassen Sie mich abschließend sagen, daß es ein Skandal wäre, zu behaupten, dieser Bericht füge der industriellen Entwicklung Schaden zu, zum einen weil dies nicht stimmt und vor allem, weil die öffentliche Gesundheit Vorrang vor allen wirtschaftlichen Erwägungen haben muß.

[image]

Edit:

Ich habe im Duden ([Link](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/komma-bei-mehrteiligen-nebensatzeinleitungen)) folgendes gefunden, weiß allerdings immer noch nicht, ob das auch nach der alten Rechtschreibung galt:

> **Komma bei mehrteiligen Nebensatzeinleitungen**
>
> ---
>
> Besteht die Einleitung eines Nebensatzes aus einer Konjunktion und weiteren Wörtern wie z. B. gerade weil, nicht weil oder sondern dass, dann wird diese Wortgruppe in der Regel nicht durch Komma geteilt; solche Fügungen werden im Allgemeinen als zusammengehörige Einheit betrachtet: 
>   Ich ziehe wieder nach München, erstens weil es meine Traumstadt ist und bleibt und zweitens weil ich wieder in der Nähe meiner Familie sein will. Ich wäre gerne dabei gewesen, aber weil ich mal wieder krank war, klappte es nicht. Nicht was du anziehst, ist entscheidend, sondern dass du freundlich und offen bist.
>
> Allerdings darf zwischen den einzelnen Bestandteilen solcher Wortgruppen ein Komma gesetzt werden, wenn der erste Teil sehr stark betont werden soll und vor der eigentlichen Konjunktion eine Sprechpause gemacht wird. Die Frage, ob Komma oder nicht, liegt also letztendlich im Ermessen des Schreibenden. Wir haben morgen ideales Grillwetter, immer vorausgesetzt(,) dass der Wetterbericht stimmt. Ein Passant hatte bereits Risse in den Pfeilern der Brücke bemerkt, zehn Tage(,) bevor sie zusammenbrach. Ich würde vorschlagen, wir erfüllen ihr diese Bitte, vor allem(,) weil sie sich immer hilfsbereit gezeigt hat.
>
> Bei mehr als zwei Einleitewörtern vor der Konjunktion sollte man jedoch ein Komma setzen, dann wird die Fügung meist nicht mehr als Einheit empfunden, z. B. es sei denn, dass, gesetzt den Fall / für den Fall, dass.

Comment: (Nebenbemerkung: Der Duden kennt zwar [interpungieren](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/interpungieren), verweist aber auf *interpunktieren*. Als Muttersprachler habe ich die erste Variante noch nie gehört, und die zweite würde ich auch nicht als Verb verwenden, sondern je nach Situation "ist die Kommasetzung/Interpunktion richtig?" o.ä.)

Comment: @dirkt auch ich bin Muttersprachler und ich bevorzuge "interpungieren" wie "fungieren" (und natürlich habe ich das Wort schon gehört und gelesen). Aber da mich auch "punktieren" nicht stört, möchte ich es nicht zur Glaubensfrage erheben. Es gab auch das Wort "pungieren" (bezogen auf Turniere) aber schon Grimm verzeichnet nur "punktieren".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deine Interpunktion und das zweite Beispiel sind auf jeden Fall korrekt.
Der jeweilige Kausalsatz wird von Kommas umschlossen, das gilt auch für die Konstruktion mit "zum einen".

Das erste Beispiel ist ja schon in sich widersprüchlich: Bei "zum einen weil" wurde kein Komma gesetzt, bei "vor allem, weil" jedoch schon.

Allerdings sieht man einen solchen Verzicht auf Interpunktion heutzutage relativ oft - die meisten Leute wollen einen Satz (verständlicherweise) nicht mit derart vielen kurz aufeinander folgenden Kommas "zerrupfen". Insbesondere, wenn es sich um die Wiedergabe eines gesprochenen Satzes handelt (das Beispiel klingt danach), bei dem man nur begrenzt oft eine Komma-Sprechpause einlegen kann, ohne dass der Redefluss gestört wird. Die fehlenden Pausen werden dann oft auch nicht mitprotokolliert.

Comment: Das ist auch meine Interpretation. Ich befürchtete aber es könne für doppelte Konstruktionen wie "zum einen weil", "aber weil" irgendwelche, womöglich fakultativen, Sonderregeln geben. Vielen Dank!

Comment: So hundertprozentig sicher bin ich mir da auch nicht, dass man die Kommas nicht mittlerweile tatsächlich weglassen darf, im Laufe der vielen Reformen der Reform der Reform der letzten Jahre wurden ja viele Regeln derart aufgeweicht, dass mehrere Schreibweisen möglich sind. Deine Version ist aber auf jeden Fall die richtige. ;)

Comment: Ein "Weil"-Satz braucht auf jeden ein Komma. Man kann hier bestenfalls untersuchen, ob das Komma vor dem ganzen Ausdruck "zum einen weil" möglich wäre.